# Spring MVC request mapping not found 404 page not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing sample Spring MVC application i want to return JSON string by requesting to spring mvc controller but when i make request via url it shows me 404 error i am following tutorial from very famous website ,My URL to which i make request IS **localhost:8080/SpringAngularProject/rest/kfc/brands/kfc1** here is my code below :

```
0-- Console Picture : 
Aug 12, 2014 7:31:19 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringAngularProject/rest/kfc/brands/sdsd] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

1- Its my Controller Class

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/kfc/brands")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName(name);
        shop.setStaffName(new String[] { "staff1", "staff2" });
        return shop;

    }
}
```

2-- My web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>AngularSpring</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>

  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

3-- My Spring cfg file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller.HelloWorldController" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

</beans>
```

4-- My pom.xml file for maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringAngularProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringAngularProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/kfc/brands/{name}"` at the intestation of your method

Comment: @AlexGreg does not work either

Comment: Try changing `<url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` and let me know

Comment: Nopes same issue :( @geoand

Comment: Have you deployed your application under the `SpringAngularProject` context?

Comment: yeah my project name is SpringAngularProject @geoand

Comment: @geoand after changing to rest/* console give me this error :WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringAngularProject/rest/kfc/brands/sdsd] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of the logs in `debug` mode when the request is made?

Comment: Can you please try `localhost:8080/rest/kfc/brands/sdsd`? Thanks

Comment: Still does not worked @geoand

Comment: Did you try the URL I suggested along with the `/rest/*` mapping?

Comment: @geoand yes i have tired it give me this error Aug 12, 2014 7:31:19 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringAngularProject/rest/kfc/brands/sdsd] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Comment: The message suggests that you have added `SpringAngularProject` to the URL. Are you sure you tested without it?

Comment: yes i have tired it many time still does not work :( @geoand

Comment: If you look at the logs Spring will tell you what URLs are mapped. Please have a look there first. If it isn't logged your controller is not picked up by the component scan.

Comment: No urls are there in log what to do now

Answer (score 1):

Finaly i got my answer myself it was just instead of  `<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller.HelloWorldController" />` i changed to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />` we just have to give path till Base package as name suggest